# Is every matrix norm compatible with a vector norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

in $\mathbb{C}^n$, I know every vector norm induces a matrix norm, and an induced matrix norm is compatible to its dedicated vector norm. So for every vector norm there exists a matrix norm, where the matrix norm is compatible with the vector norm. But is the other implication true too?

Is there for every matrix norm a vector norm it is compatible with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. This is the result of theorem 5.7.13 on p.373 of Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis* (2/e).

A (submultiplicative) matrix norm $\|\cdot\|_M$ is said to be compatible with a vector norm $\|\cdot\|_v$ if $\|Ax\|_v\le\|A\|_M\|x\|_v$ for every matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ and every vector $v\in\mathbb C^n$. Now, given any matrix norm $\|\cdot\|_M$, we pick a fixed but arbitrary nonzero vector $y$ and define a vector norm $\|\cdot\|_v$ by $\|x\|_v=\|xy^\ast\|_M$. Then $\|\cdot\|_M$ is compatible with $\|\cdot\|_v$ because
$$
\|Ax\|_v=\|Axy^\ast\|_M\le\|A\|_M\|xy^\ast\|_M=\|A\|_M\|x\|_v.
$$

Comment: Thank you! But can you briefly explain why the first equality in the last line states? Somehow I just do not get it

Comment: @HyperPro $\|u\|_v$ is *defined* to be $\|uy^\ast\|_M$. Now put $u=Ax$.

Comment: @user1551 ok dat was obvious, I feel so dumb. But thank you again.